# How many female romantic interests with initials "L.L." were there in Superman's life?

Tags: dc, superman

We all know that Superman's "main" romantic interests had alliterative names with "L.L." initials - Lois Lane, Lana Lang. I know that there were others following the same pattern.

We also know that alliterative names in general [were common](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/why-are-there-so-many-double-initials-in-comic-books) in comics, especially Superman.

**How many female characters with initials "L.L." was there in Superman's life and who were they?** (Names only will suffuce, but short blurbs on their relationship with Superman would make the answer much better).

**Details:**

- Anyone female (of any species, human, alien, mutant, whatnot) counts.
- Must have some sort of **romantic/sexual interest with Superman** (from either side - e.g. the interest need not be mutual).
- Any Superman-containing franchise counts (comics, movies, TV series).
- Any continuity/Earth-N counts
- If the name contains 3+ words, both first word and one more must start with "L" (but not necessarily every word)

Comment: LL? Lex Luthor! ;)

Comment: By the way, http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/LL

Comment: @MarkBeadles +1 Ahahah! That was good! Lex is definitely a romantic interest of his! :D

Answer (score 16):

Some that come to mind are:

1. Lana Lang - his first girlfriend
2. Lori Lemaris - his sweetheart
3. Lois Lane - his wife
4. Lyla Lerrol - love from homeworld
5. Luma Lynai - love interest
6. Lola-La - almost married her
7. Lutessa Luthor (aka Tess Mercer)
8. Lourdes Lucero (aka La Encantadora) - romance
9. Lydia Lawrence - girlfriend before Lois Lane

Comment: don't forget Lara Lor-Van, his mother on Krypton

Comment: I don't think his mum counts as a romantic interest...

Comment: Maybe its an ediple thing that drives the LL obsession :)

Comment: I'll accept if you explain where you obtained the list and show that there's a reason it's exaustive.

Comment: Maybe they got the list from http://www.dialbforblog.com/archives/323/?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile By memory and other sources, created lists as a kid, don't remember and cannot reference them now. Later I added those two that I found on the net.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I should think not, but thanks, now we can add more names.

Answer (score 7):

**Additional** - Superman #157 - "Superman's Day of Doom!" featured Superman remembering all the "L.L." people that had come into his life, including the ones above, as well as Lex Luthor, Linda Lee (Supergirl's first secret identity), Lightning Lad, et al.

[image]

He had received a prediction that his life would be saved by an "L.L." and was trying to figure out who is would be.

Eventually a young boy came along to help him, a "Little Leaguer"

[image]