# Was Superman Romantically Involved With Any Females Without the Initials "L.L."?

Tags: dc, superman

A question that was asked recently and that I really enjoyed is:
[How many female romantic interests with initials "L.L." were there in Superman's life?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/how-many-female-romantic-interests-with-initials-l-l-were-there-in-supermans)

I wanted to expand on this and ask about other characters that Superman was romantically involved with, but who don't have the initials L.L.

**Was Superman involved with any female characters *without* the intials "L.L."?** The answer can include female characters of any species from any of the Superman franchises (comics, TV, movies, etc).

Comment: I mind if the answer is >= 1. This will destroy the orderly view of the world :)

Comment: Does this qualify as a list question?

Comment: @HNL: This question is fine, there's a finite number of possibilities.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - you mean you can't come up with an infinite number of names?

Comment: @Jeff: An infinite number of names, sure, but not an infinite number of names that fit the criteria of having some involvement with Superman.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: Apparently, he lives well into the 700th millenium and can access the 5th dimension.  That list could be a LOOOOOONG one.

Comment: @Jeff: I guess that's what I get for not knowing all of Superman lore...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since I answered @DVK's [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/how-many-female-romantic-interests-with-initials-l-l-were-there-in-supermans), I'm going to try to answer this one.

Non L.L. relationships:

1. Alicia Baker
2. Amazing Grace
3. Angela Blake
4. Big Barda - Barda Free
5. Catherine Grant
6. Chloe Sullivan
7. Dana Dearden
8. Diana Stride
9. Eve Teschmacher
10. Futura (aka Mekanique)
11. Hana
12. Helena Bertinelli
13. Jessie Brooks
14. Joyce White (robot)
15. Kara Zor-El
16. Kara Zor-L
17. Kyla Willowbrook
18. Lacy Warfield
19. Linda Danvers
20. Lindsey Harrison
21. Loana (a dream)
22. Lorelei Ambrosia
23. Lyra 3619
24. Mandy
25. Mari McCabe
26. Maxima
27. Mindy
28. Orella
29. Queen Latora
30. Rija
31. Sally Selwyn
32. Saturn Girl (Imra Ardeen)
33. Simone Charcot
34. Tinya Wazzo
35. Wonder Woman
36. Zara-Ra
37. Zatanna Zatara

Comment: Did he really have a relationship with all of those women, or were those women just people interested in him?  I know he had a child with Wonder Woman (Did he call her Londer Loman?) in one book, but I thought that was not from the normal continuity.

Comment: @Jeff I'm trying to find all the references to link them. I'm going to update my question soon. As for the name Londer Loman, I cannot recall. The question asks about all franchises, so I'm trying to list them all. There are probably many more.

Comment: If this was taken from some wiki or any other internet source, you should reference it.

Comment: @bitmask I knew of some of the names, but I asked a few friends that are Superman fans to help, and they sent me a few name's via email. If they did a search, I don't know. I'm doing a search for issues to link the characters with events.

Comment: @Secko: In that case: Awesome job! :)

Comment: Really, Kara? ick? Plus didn't she go by "Linda Lee" early on, so she'd be an LL :)

Comment: @jeff that was in the dark knight strikes again by frank miller, her name was 'lara' but don't remember the last name.