# Why does Stan Lee name characters first and last names alike?

Tags: marvel, stan-lee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Are There So Many Double Initials in Comic Books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/why-are-there-so-many-double-initials-in-comic-books)

Peter Parker, Bruce Banner, etc etc etc. The list goes on and on.
Why did Stan Lee name his characters like this? He seems to be obsessed with alliteration.

Comment: It turns out he thought he could remember them better.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting so many down votes? Surely just a flag or a VTC would be sufficient?

Comment: Because it is a question people have seen and has been asked before now. Most will request people redirect their search to the already existing question.

Comment: @Thaddeus That is what the VTC option and flagging as duplicates are there for isn't it? Just because the question has been asked before doesn't mean it is a bad question. Plus being a new user we should be welcoming him to the community with constructive criticism not down votes shouldn't we?

Comment: NominSim, I am certainly not the person to ask about down-voting. I try not to do down votes at all. If a question is that bad, I try to improve it, or if it is a problem, I vote to close it, but I don't take points from others, if I can help it. It is an issue of culture how people view voting. I have had the rare distinction of being given the check for a question, but not actually being voted on by the person who gives me the vote for my answer. I do my best to be supportive of everyone who posts here.