# Superman: why so many "LL" initials?

Tags: dc, superman

Why are there so many significant characters in Superboy, Superman with the same initials LL? For instance Lana Lang, Lois Lane, Lex Luthor, Lena Luthor, Linda Lee, ....? For Batman all I can recall for anything similar is Vicki Vale.

Comment: There's already an answer to this question addressing the L.L. pattern: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/why-are-there-so-many-double-initials-in-comic-books/

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer on that question addresses “L. L.” specifically.

Comment: Though, it never took off with Batman?

Comment: @jim if the rumor about Joe Shuster is correct, then the same personal connection wouldn't be there when Batman was being created.